# Logstash agent doesn't run as an daemon on MAC OS X 10.9.1

Tags: macos, plist, daemon, boot, logstash

I need to run the logstash agent as a Daemon on an MAC OS X System whenever the system boots up

> terminal: **/usr/local/logstash/bin/logstash agent -f /usr/local/etc/cvlog.conf**

Per terminal the program is working succesfully but as an daemon it doesn't start.

**My com.bcd.logstash.plist**

```
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>Label</key>
  <string>com.bcd.logstash</string>
  <key>KeepAlive</key>
  <dict>
    <key>SuccessfulExit</key>
    <false />
  </dict>

  <key>ProgramArguments</key> 
  <array>
      <string>/usr/local/logstash/bin/logstash</string>
      <string>agent</string>
      <string>-f</string>
      <string>/usr/local/etc/cvlog.conf</string>
  </array>
  
  <key>RunAtLoad</key>
  <true/> 
</dict>
</plist>
```

I start with:

> launchtl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.bcd.logstash.plist

Syslog Error Message

> com.apple.launchd[1] (com.bcd.logstash[pid]): Exited with code:1
>
> com.apple.launchd[1] (com.bcd.logstash[pid]): Exited with code:143

What's wrong with my plist?

Answer (score 1):

**Short version**: 
When running from launchd at startup, there is no $HOME environment variable. The default value for the location of sincedb_path is thus invalid. You can specify it by adding a line such as `sincedb_path => "/usr/local/logstash/.sincedb"` to each input file in your logstash config.

**Long version**:

I ran in to the same problem. I monitored the output of logstash by adding these lines to the plist:

```
<key>StandardErrorPath</key>
<string>/Library/Logs/LittleSnitchDaemon.log</string>
<key>StandardOutPath</key>
<string>/Library/Logs/LittleSnitchDaemon.log</string>
```

I found the error: `"No SINCEDB_DIR or HOME environment variable set, I don't know where to keep track of the files I'm watching. Either set HOME or SINCEDB_DIR in your environment, or set sincedb_path in in your Logstash config for the file input with path '[\"/var/log/apache2/access_log\"]'"`

Eventually I found https://logstash.jira.com/browse/LOGSTASH-1967. It appeared to describe the same problem. I solved it by adding the paramteter `sincedb_path => "/usr/local/logstash/.sincedb"` to each log file I am reading.